# Why is DataBricks's Spark running slightly faster in Python than Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

​For my Azure DataBricks, I created two notebooks, ExtractorPython and ExtractorScala, which are written in Python and Scala respectively. They each call the notebook, DocumentationPython and DocumentationScala, respectively.

In both Allergies notebook, an example code would check if a table, ProblemData, exists. If so, it will join 4 other tables together to insert into the main table Documentation. The table ranges in size from 6 MB to 2800 MB. Here is an example Documentation code in Python:

```
IfExtsDf = sqlContext.sql("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'ProblemData '")

#If ProblemData exists then insert data from query into Documentation
if IfExtsDf.head(1):
  spark.sql(
  "INSERT INTO Documentation "+
  "SELECT " +
  "EPA.Field1, " +
  "msa.Field2, " +
  "RAM.Field3 " +
  "FROM ProblemData AS EPA " + 
  "INNER JOIN MedicalRecordNumbers AS msa ON " + 
  "  msa.MisAllrgID = EPA.AllergenID AND " + 
  "  msa.SourceID   = EPA.SourceID AND " + 
  "  msa.EhrId      = EPA.EhrId " + 
  "LEFT JOIN  Staging_Main AS RAM ON " + 
  "  RAM.PatientID = EPA.PatientID AND " + 
  "  RAM.SourceID  = EPA.SourceID AND " + 
  "  RAM.EhrId     = EPA.EhrId" 
  )
```

The query is more complex than that with  8 regular inserts and 3 conditional inserts into the Documentation table, but I cannot show more than that.
Here is the basic extractor code in Python:

```
#Run DocumentationPython
dbutils.notebook.run("DocumentationPython",0)
```

Here is my Spark cluster configuration of two nodes:

[image: cluster]

Here is the speed test for Python vs Scala in minutes for multiple runs:

**ExtractorPython**: 3.22 minute

**DocumentationPython**: 2.78 minute

**ExtractorScala**: 3.24 minute

**DocumentationScala**: 2.88 minute

Here is the speed test when I bumped up the cluster to 6 nodes:

**ExtractorPython**: 2.22 minute

**DocumentationPython**: 1.95 minute

**ExtractorScala**:  minute

**DocumentationScala**: 1.98 minute

I have read that Scala should be faster than Python. Some [articles](https://www.dezyre.com/article/scala-vs-python-for-apache-spark/213) said it is 10 times faster. My test reveals that there is no differences and Python is slightly faster. Why is that?

In addition, why is calling a notebook from another notebook adds an average of 20 seconds, e.g., calling DocumentationPython from ExtractorPython?

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried with Python vs Scala in your example. You're mainly using hive sql.

Comment: @RuiLima why does it not matter when Hive Sql is involved?

Comment: if you are executing hivesql you're not really using python nor scala, the sql is executed by hive the same way regardless if you called it from a session in python or a session in scala. Now if you were actually reading the data, let's say with a collect() then it would matter (serialization and whatnot), but you are doing an insert into from a sql so it doesnt really matter. It's the same as you executing a SQL from C# or from Python, the SQL is really executed by Oracle (or whatever dbms you use). "Dont quote me, I am not really an expert on spark"

Answer (score 0):

One reason Scala code is faster than Python, is because Scala code is pre-compiled into Bytecode. In databricks, each code-clock is compiled on the runtime and there is no pre-defined JAR.

I think, for this reason, in a notebook environment, Scala/Java any compiled language loses any advantage over an interpreted language like Python.